# Sorting the results of an NSFetchRequest of objects that implement compare:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I have a `NSManagedObject` subclass that implements the `compare:` message. I want to retrieve these objects and sort them using this compare method, but apparently I have to provide a `key` for the `NSSortDescriptor`.

I don't want to provide any `key`, as the object itself already knows how to compare itself.

If I provide nil as the key for the key:

```
r.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil
                                                        ascending:YES                                                        selector:@selector(compare:)]];
```

I get the following error:

> failed: ((62) equal to ([[self.lib tags] count])) failed: throwing
>   "keypath #self not found in entity "

How can I make sure that `NSSortDescriptor` ignores any `key` and just uses `compare:` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a SQLite store, and you can only use modelled properties in a NSFetchRequest that relies on a SQLite store.

It was very confusing, as it worked on my tests (I was using an In Memory store) and failed miserably in the App itself. A better error description would have saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try supplying the key `@"self"`?